# How to handle browser 'back' & 'refresh' with AJAX content on a page (so the content matches the form that loads it)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble searching for an answer to this, I think because the key words are too general and related to other things.

I have an index page with a records search form (AJAX) used to load records into the main div on the page.  When the page first loads, the form is set to a specific state based on who the user and the contents of the div are loaded based on the same criteria.  When the form is submitted the contents of the main div are replaced via AJAX.

If a user clicks a browsers REFRESH button, or goes to another page and clicks the browser BACK button, the index page comes up with the form in the same state it was when the user clicked BACK or REFRESH but the div contents are the original default contente.  This makes it looks like the items listed are a result of the forms current state.

Is there a way way to detect if the page has been displayed from a a BACK or REFRESH browser action so that I could trigger the form to submit and update the contents based on the current state of the search form ($('#search_form_submit_button').click();)?   Or, what is the proper thing to do for this?

Thanks - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form has a default value such as "" or "Search here.." you could  check if the default value has changed and then submit the form:

```
// If the input value is different from the know default
if($("#search_form_input").val() != "Search here..") {

  // Update the results on the page
  $('#search_form_submit_button').click();

}
```

And call that on page ready - so inside the `$(function(){ /* content here */ });`

Also, have a look at History.js - https://github.com/browserstate/History.js

It provides a really complete history management system. It supports jQuery amongst several other libraries.

### **EDIT:**

---

I will address some things Reno mentioned in his comment.

You can use this small library [Session variables](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) to persist data over page changes. Download the js file from that link and include it in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sessionvars.js"></script>
```

Then when a user makes a search, store the search in the `sessvars` object which is now available across pages:

```
sessvars.myObj = { searched: $("#Search_form_input").val() }
```

Then when the page loads, check if sessvars.myObj.search has a value in it. If it does then search for that value:

```
if(sesvars && sessvars.myObj && sessvars.myObj.searched) {
  $("#Search_form_input").val(sessvars.myObj.searched);
  $('#search_form_submit_button').click();
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't have a known default value because it can change as the user uses the form.  I actually didn't know document ready scripts are executed on a browser refresh or back.  --- Following your logic I could stick "form has not changed" into a hidden div and replace the contents with "form has changed" if an ajax call is made, then have the page ready script check the value of that div to know to submit the form or not.   I'll try that in a bit and accept your answer if it works - thank you!

Comment: Content changed by javascript in the DOM will not persist over page refreshes or back button usage. You could look at something like this: http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html to persist data over pages using javascript. So, after including the JS file from that link you could write `sessvars.myObj = {searched: "search_value"}` when a search is made and then onload check if `sessvars.myObj.searched` is there and if it is, commence the search..

Comment: Yeah that was dumb of me - you can't change the page as a marker when a refresh/back goes back to the original page state except for the form state passed through params.   Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I didn't need to use the Session Variables plugin as I'm already using Session Variables in Rails.   I just created a new one called "index_ajax" that gets changed to 'none' or 'changed' based on an initial page load or ajax update.  Then I'm just injecting the state of the Rails session variable into the Javascript statement.  It's always fun when when you dynamically write part of a script with another language.  :)   if('<%= session[:index_ajax]' == 'changed) {

Answer (score 1):

See the [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin.